# COUNT(*) returning multiple rows instead of just one

Tags: mysql, count

Why does COUNT() return multiple rows when I just need the total count of how many rows my query generates?

Should return 1078.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `COUNT()` is working as expected. When you put a `group by` clause, the `count()` gives you the result for `GROUP BY`. If you wish to get the count of rows in a query that includes `group by`, use it as a subquery instead.

Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `table`
                      GROUP BY `column1`) AS `a`
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, simple answer. Don't `GROUP BY` if you don't need groups.

Either use `COUNT(DISTINCT articles.company)` without `GROUP BY` or keep the the `GROUP BY` and wrap the whole query in a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) AS data`, if you want to count the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use *group by*, it will count the number of each *group*.

Comment: Well I actually *need* GROUP BY, so it should return the correct figure.

Comment: @silkfire yes. if you need, it will return the count of each group. And if you wanna return the count of all items, just remove group by.

Answer (score 0):

Write the above query as subquery then it will give proper result and dont use group by

```
select count(*) from (select articles.id from 'contract_prices' left join 'articles' on
    (arcticles.id = contract_prices.article) 
    where 'contract_to' >= curdate()
    )
```