# Get total rows using HAVING to condition

Tags: mysql

The following query returns the results limited to 20 rows and where there is no filter id 6 applied.

```
SELECT p.id, p.description
FROM   product p
LEFT JOIN product_filter pf 
ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE  p.status = TRUE
GROUP  BY p.id
HAVING SUM(pf.filter_id = '6') = 0 
ORDER  BY p.description ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

This works great, but now I'd like to count the amount of rows with the same condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS total 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_filter pf 
ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.status = TRUE
HAVING SUM(pf.filter_id = 6) = 0
```

And this query returns me zero results.

**EDIT**: As requested, **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00b12/3)** to help view the problem in a more detailed way.

Comment: Have you tried it with removing distinct?

Comment: Where are the table structures and example data? When you provide you get better answers

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, yes and I get the same behavior, no results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland post edited

Comment: You never say what your query does, or what is suppose to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the @Raymond Nijland answer is the correct, in my environment the code he suggested did not work.

By taking a look at this post [COUNT(*) returning multiple rows instead of just one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309899/count-returning-multiple-rows-instead-of-just-one) I manage to make it work by doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS total 
FROM (SELECT p2.id 
      FROM product AS p2 
      LEFT JOIN product_filter pf 
        ON pf.product_id = p2.id 
      GROUP BY p2.id 
      HAVING SUM(pf.filter_id = '6') = 0) As p
```

Comment: Is this a comment or the final answer?

Comment: btw you dont need `DISTINCT` your subquery already have `GROUP BY id`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza final answer, will accept tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You missed GROUP BY p.id.
HAVING without GROUP BY doesn't work.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS total 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_filter pf 
ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.status = TRUE
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(pf.filter_id = 6) = 0
```

Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00b12/6

Comment: I have tested before with the `GROUP BY` clause but it didn't work in my environment because it gives me lots of rows https://s26.postimg.org/bg3m3zdwp/notitle.png