# MYSQL COUNT(column) returns multiple lines unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have two tables:

**1. SELECT * FROM gas_trades_bids;**

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | claim_id | amount | lots_value | timestmp   |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|  5 |       9 |       11 |     60 |       NULL | 1571317861 |
|  6 |       9 |       11 |    100 |       NULL | 1571656888 |
|  7 |       9 |       11 |     50 |       NULL | 1571727353 |
|  8 |       9 |       11 |     50 |       NULL | 1571918296 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2. SELECT * FROM gas_trades_offers;**

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
| id | user_id | claim_id | amount | lots_value | accepted | timestmp   |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
|  8 |       9 |       11 |     33 |         22 |     NULL | 1571918576 |
|  9 |       9 |       11 |     33 |         22 |        1 | 1571918576 |
| 10 |       9 |       11 |     33 |         22 |        1 | 1571918576 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The goals are:

1. Count the amount of the rows where gas_trades_bids.claim_id = gas_trades_offers_claim_id and gas_trades_bids.claim_id = 11 and gas_trades_bids.user_id = 11
2. Get the sum of the column gas_trades_offers.lots_value values

To reach this I tried to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(bids.id) amount, SUM(offers.lots_value) 
  FROM gas_trades_offers offers, (SELECT * FROM gas_trades_bids) bids 
 WHERE bids.user_id = 9 
   AND bids.user_id = offers.user_id
```

But I've got the multiple rows:'

```
+--------+------------------------+
| amount | SUM(offers.lots_value) |
+--------+------------------------+
|      3 |                     66 |
|      3 |                     66 |
|      3 |                     66 |
|      3 |                     66 |
+--------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What do I do in the wrong way?

I have expected to get only:

```
+--------+------------------------+
| amount | SUM(offers.lots_value) |
+--------+------------------------+
|      3 |                     66 |
+--------|------------------------|
```

**I don't need to use GROUP BY!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COUNT(\*) returning multiple rows instead of just one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309899/count-returning-multiple-rows-instead-of-just-one)

Comment: @Casper Nah, I don't need to use GROUP BY syntax. You are mistaken

Comment: which exactly table that you want to count (id)? I don't understand well about that point. Could you explain more? If count from bids it will return 4, count from orders will return 3

Comment: @momo I would like to count the rows from `gas_trades_bids` where the column `claim_id` should be equivalent to `gas_trades_offers.claim_id`

Comment: do you mean where the value of column gas_trades_bids.claim_id should have existed in gas_trades_offers?

Comment: @momo yes, correct

Comment: please reference the query I posted in the answer. Does it work for your case?

Comment: Your query does not return 4 rows for the sample data that you posted: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j7k6jrKFVQNZkeHmxGAuAb/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it exactly what you need? Hope that this query can work well.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(offers.id) amount,
       SUM(offers.lots_value)
FROM gas_trades_offers offers
WHERE offers.user_id = 9 and offers.claim_id = 11
      AND exists (SELECT id FROM gas_trades_bids bids WHERE bids.claim_id = offers.claim_id and bids.user_id = offers.user_id)
```

Comment: yes, it is. Thank you, so much! Could you explain why have I got the multiple rows in my case?

Comment: I tried your query on my sample data. But it returned only 1 record which amount = 12 & sum = 264. Seems it counts & sums from the join result.

Comment: Have you used PDO at the moment?

Comment: No, I used mysql with the tool phpMyadmin for testing your query

Comment: You've got the row with the summarized columns. Your result is wrong. After running your query, I've got 
amount  - 3, SUM(offers.lots_value) - 66

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(bids.id) amount,
       SUM(offers.lots_value)
FROM gas_trades_offers offers
JOIN gas_trade_bids bids ON bids.user_id = offers.user_id
WHERE offers.user_id = 9;
```

Comment: It returns me this:

Comment: amount - 12
SUM(offers.lots_value) - 264

Comment: It looks like the sum of the multiple rows from COUNT

Comment: 4 * 3 = 12, 66 * 4 = 264